# Good multithreading guides?

Tags: c++, multithreading

I'm looking for a good guide/tutorial on multithreading in C++ (and ideally in general). Can anyone point me to a good online resource?

EDIT: I intend to familiarize myself with either the boost threading library or the one from Poco.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279009

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Dr. Dobbs article "[The Boost.Threads Library](http://www.ddj.com/cpp/184401518)" is a short introduction to the subject, using one of the [Boost C++ Libraries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boost_C%2B%2B_Libraries).

Comment: Yep, that's a good start

Answer (score 4):

That's not a tutorial, but a good set of articles [Effective Concurrency](http://herbsutter.wordpress.com/2009/08/11/effective-concurrency-design-for-manycore-systems/) by Herb Sutter.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at *[Concurrent Programming on Windows](http://www.bluebytesoftware.com/books/winconc/winconc_book_resources.html)* by *Joe Duffy*. The book is relative new (November 2008) and covers theory and practice ranging topics from the Win32 API to .NET Framework 3.5.

[image: Concurrent Programming on Windows]
<sub>(source: [barnesandnoble.com](http://images.barnesandnoble.com/images/28320000/28320195.JPG))</sub>

Answer (score 1):

If you mean to parallelize computation for multi-core, check out [OpenMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenMP).  It has gcc and intel (I'm not sure about Visual C++) support, and is a lot easier than using primitives.

Comment: Thanks for the link, I did not know about OpenMP before. I find this very interesting, however, my main goal is to find a good guide about multithreading like how to use locks, how to avoid deadlocks, etc...

Comment: I'd be interested in an answer to that, too.  It's tricky, so higher level constructs should be favored.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this useful video-lectures from Intel: http://software.intel.com/en-us/videos/three-things-you-must-teach-module-1-recognizing-potential-parallelism/

This tutorial covers:

- Importance of parallelism
- Shared memory model and threads
- OpenMP basics

The video tutorial is very short: about 60 minutes, so I hope you will find it useful.

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to use boost::thread, I'd make sure to check out [Anthony Williams' website, blogs and articles](http://www.justsoftwaresolutions.co.uk/) he maintains boost::thread contributed to the C++0x library particularly the threading components and the information he provides is accurate, relevant and concise.

He also has a book coming out this fall on modern C++ threading called Concurrency in Action.

[Joe Duffy's book and blog](http://www.bluebytesoftware.com/blog/Default.aspx) is also a good resource.