# Where can I find Multithreading tutorials?

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi, visual-c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C++ multithreading tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279009/c-multithreading-tutorial)

I have a project I need to deliver and were supposed to use multi-threading using WIN32 API.
I am a beginner at windows programming and I need a helpful tutorial that can help me with that, any recommendations?

I'm using Visual Studio C++

Comment: Using which programming language?

Comment: C++, iam using visual studios

Comment: @Anon, don't do `anything...????`, you only asked the question 8 minutes ago.

Comment: @Anon, you have been given a link to another thread. Check it out.

Comment: @Anon please read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq)

Comment: @Anon: You could search if already a Q similar to yours exists on SO. It would save You the overhead of posting it and save us the overhead of marking it duplicate. See the marked duplicate.

Comment: @Als: but that would have required effort on OP's part.  It's much easier for *us* to to the work, is it not?

Comment: If I were to write a _tutorial_ on multithreading, I'd call it "How to shoot yourself in the foot for dummies". Sigh, maybe the OP should have started learning about threads some time ago, not just in the last minute.

Answer (score 1):

As simple as it gets.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void my_function(char* parameter){
  cout << parameter;
}

int main(){

char* passpointer = "hahaha";

HANDLE recvhand = CreateThread(NULL,0,(LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)my_function,passpointer,0,NULL);

Sleep(1000);

}
```

**Basically**
you can use the `CreateThread` function just like you see it, for any simple threading. If you need more advanced help, you can ask specific addressable questions, or you can do some advanced google searching =)

Comment: if you use CreateThread(), you cannot use any of the C Run Time Library (RTL).  i.e. functions like strcpy(), printf() and atoi().  It is usually recommended that you use _beginthread() or _beginthreadex() instead.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682453%28VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: Interesting. Does that produce any additional overhead? I haven't found any need to use the RTL functions in my threads up to this point, the majority has been working with networking or simple jobs passed in with functors...

Comment: I don't have any figures on overhead, but I wouldn't think it would be much extra.  Mostly at startup and shutdown time.  If you are creating and destroying large numbers of threads it might be an issue, but if that is the case you will probably do better using a thread pool rather than continued creation and destruction.

Comment: I agree with the threadpool vector.

Answer (score 0):

Seriously, I think you are in trouble.  Multithreaded programming is fairly hard, and it is unreasonable for a novice programmer to expect to get it right.

Is this homework, or are you doing it for an employer (or something else)?

Comment: I think this could've been a comment.

Comment: Although this is full of good intentions, and very true, I don't think it answers the question at all.

Comment: That's what I meant (y) And that's why I didn't down-voted (:

Comment: I thought is did answer the question, though in a negative way: I don't think it is possible.